# Access a Canvas inside an ItemsSource in a UserControl, from the MainPage

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a `FlipView` in my `MainPage`. It's `ItemTemplate` binded to a `UserControl` called `landscapeControl`. It's `ItemsSource` is binded to a List of a class called  `MyLandscape`.

landscapeControl:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="LScrollViewer" MaxZoomFactor="2.0" MinZoomFactor="1.0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" DoubleTapped="LScrollViewer_DoubleTapped" >
        <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Background="Transparent">
            <StackPanel x:Name="LStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Image x:Name="LImage0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Source="{Binding firstImage}" Width="570"/>
                <Image x:Name="LImage1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Source="{Binding nextImage}" Width="570"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

`MyLandscape` class:

```
    public class MyLandscape
    {
        public ImageSource firstImage { get; set; }
        public ImageSource nextImage { get; set; }
        public Canvas inkCanvas { get; set; }
    }
```

My images are showing perfectly. All I want is 3 things:

1) I want to access my `Canvas` from my `MainPage`. I am trying to do this in  `flipView_SelectionChanged` event:

```
        landscapeControl pc = flipView1.SelectedItem as landscapeControl;

        if (flipView1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var myCanvas = pc.getCanvas();
            m_CanvasManager = new CanvasManager(myCanvas);
        }
```

But the pc variable is always null! I want to bind my `Canvas`, so I have a `Canvas` for every two images? 
Is that possible?

Comment: in your flipView_SelectionChanged event, can you call e.AddedItems ?
if so, change your code:
if (flipView1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var myCanvas = pc.getCanvas();
            m_CanvasManager = new CanvasManager(myCanvas);
        }
to 
if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var myCanvas = (e.AddedItems as LandscapeControl).getCanvas();
            m_CanvasManager = new CanvasManager(myCanvas);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a `Command` to pass an `UIElement` back to your model.

Basically your `inkCanvas` element will be attached with a `CanvasLoadedCommand` like this. Note this command is only called when the `inkCanvas` is fully loaded.

```
    <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Background="Transparent">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasLoadedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=inkCanvas}" />
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I have created a simple `DelegateCommand` for this little [demo](http://1drv.ms/1ID6kE5) (working source code) here. When the `inkCanvas` is loaded,

> this.inkCanvas = (Canvas)canvas;

will be called and the `inkCanvas` property will then be filled.

```
    private DelegateCommand _canvasLoadedCommand;
    public DelegateCommand CanvasLoadedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_canvasLoadedCommand == null)
            {
                _canvasLoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand((canvas) =>
                {
                    this.inkCanvas = (Canvas)canvas;
                }, 
                (canvas) => canvas != null);
            }

            return _canvasLoadedCommand;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"` can't be recognized when added to my UserControl. How can I define `Interactivity`? or is it a Reference I should download?

Comment: Add Reference, then select Behaviors SDK in Extensions tab.

Comment: Implemented! And the returned inkCanvas is always null :(

Comment: Yea, I've did the same as yours and it is still null. Would you mind checking my second question? It's an easier turn of I wanted to do here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236107/zooming-into-all-content-of-a-canvas

Comment: Swipe the flipview in my sample, and you will see it's not null... Why not solve this issue first?

Comment: The very first time, it's null because the Canvas is not even loaded yet. However if you put a breakpoint in `this.inkCanvas = (Canvas)canvas;` you will notice this line will be called when the Canvas is loaded. Then when you swipe left or right the Canvas will never be null again.

Comment: The thing is that my DataTemplate has a seperate UserControl class, I don't think it affects the result, but getLoadedCommand is not being called. I have put it in Xaml as you did thought.

Comment: There must be something wrong, can you show some code?

Comment: Sorry, [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7eb4ee26b92f0ded!13661&authkey=!AHWAc2XH5O_Idzw&ithint=file%2czip) it is

Comment: You need to do a simple `flipView1.SelectedItem` null check... 'cause the very first time the SelectedItem is null. It's in my demo.

Comment: Didn't work! Have you tried it on my code? It's null!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77894/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-layale-matta).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from:

```
if (flipView1.Items.Count > 0) { 
    var myCanvas = pc.getCanvas(); 
    m_CanvasManager = new CanvasManager(myCanvas);
}
```

to

```
if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0) { 
    var myCanvas = (e.AddedItems[0] as LandscapeControl).getCanvas(); 
    m_CanvasManager = new CanvasManager(myCanvas); 
}
```

Comment: I had a **NullReferenceException** at `var myCanvas = (e.AddedItems[0] as landscapeControl).getCanvas();`

Comment: Layale, you have landscapeControl user control and MyLandscape class, what is the relation between landscapeControl and MyLandscape ?

Comment: shouldn't you have landscapeControl.xaml and landscapeControl.xaml.cs ?

Comment: Of course I have `landscapeControl.xaml` and `landscapeControl.xaml.cs`, the 2 images in the `landscapeControl` are binded to the Images generated by the class `MyLandscape`. I have added a `Canvas` to the `MyLandscape` class but I don't know how I should bind it to the `Canvas` in the `landscapeControl`, so I can have a `Canvas` for every 2 images for every `SelectedIndex` in the `FlipView`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a long search, in `Windows Store Apps`: We **can't** access a `Canvas` that's inside a `FlipView`, either if it is directly inside the `FlipView` or in the `DataTemplate` of the `FlipView`.

Comment: Not true. The `SelectedItem` is type of `MyLandscape`, not `landscapeControl`. If you databind the `inkCanvas` properly, you should be able to get the `Canvas` instance from `((MyLandscape)flipView1.SelectedItem).inkCanvas`.

Comment: The real question is How to databind the inkCanvas properly?

Comment: Do you have Command & CommandParameter implemented in your project?

Comment: Nope! Any link I can follow to implement them?

Comment: @JustinXL Do you have an idea about this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236107/zooming-into-all-content-of-a-canvas

Comment: I am preparing an answer for this question, give me a few more mins. :)