# Zooming into all content of a Canvas

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, scrollviewer

I have this Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="DrawingGrid" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="ExitDrawingButton" Icon="Cancel" Click="ExitDrawingButton_Click"></AppBarButton>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DScrollViewer" ManipulationMode="All"  MaxZoomFactor="2.0" MinZoomFactor="1.0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" DoubleTapped="DScrollViewer_DoubleTapped" Width="1140" Height="770">
            <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Background="Transparent" Width="1140" Height="770">
                <StackPanel x:Name="DStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Image x:Name="DImage0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Source="{Binding nextImage}" Width="570" Canvas.ZIndex="0"/>
                    <Image x:Name="DImage1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Source="{Binding nextImage}" Width="570" Canvas.ZIndex="0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

I am drawing on `Canvas` using the CanvasManager.cs class and it is working fine.
Now I need to zoom on the `Canvas`: Zoom the `Canvas` (the ink) and Zoom what it contains (the `StackPanel` + the Images) together.

On `doubleTapping` the `ScrollViewer` containing the `Canvas` I have this method:

```
 private async void DScrollViewer_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = e.GetPosition(DScrollViewer);
        if (DScrollViewer.ZoomFactor == 1)
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            DScrollViewer.ChangeView(point.X, point.Y, 2.0F, false);
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            DScrollViewer.ChangeView(point.X, point.Y, 1.0F, false);
        }
    }
```

The result is: only the `Canvas` (its Ink) is Zooming and the `StackPanel` and its Images are left at the place, same scale, intact!

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had a look at your demo and found that the `Images` are actually sitting inside a different `ScrollViewer` (`LScrollViewer`) while the `ScrollViewer` (`DScrollViewer`) is responsible for zooming. This might be why those images are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is you are assign a constant value for the width of each image (`Width="570"`) so that it will never zoomed in or out unless you have change it's width programmatically.

The best way to change the image's width is bind a variable value for it, you can create a converter that divide the width of canvas over two (canvas.width / 2) and bind the width of each image to this converter..
Then your zoom will work perfectly.

Comment: Not true, I removed the Width of the Images completely, and I still have the same problem. I think the Canvas hide every control that is under it.